# Multiple full-screen windows with DirectX 9.0

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

This is a bit of an edge case but I am developing a game which uses multiple monitors. For reasons outside the scope of this question, I am using a 'multi-device method' rather than swap chains. My code is similar to the following sample:

http://www.codesampler.com/dx9src/dx9src_1.htm#dx9_multiple_devices

What I'm struggling with, and what I can find no documentation about, is whether it's possible to run both windows in true full-screen (i.e `d3dpp.Windowed = FALSE;`). Currently I'm getting an 'invalid params' HRESULT when calling `CreateDevice` the second time. It works fine if *one* of the windows is full-screen, but not both. I'm hoping there's a setting to make this work though...

Cheers in advance

Comment: Just wondering, was the reason for using multiple adapters rather than additional swapchains because of screen tearing? If so, I'm in the same exact boat as you, and have been rewriting my renderer for the past week :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the Direct3D 9 documentation ([Working with Multiple Monitor Systems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)): "The practical implication is that a multiple monitor application can place several devices in full-screen mode, but only if all these devices are for different adapters, were created by the same Direct3D9 object, and all share the same focus window."

You'll notice that there are two window handles per device initialization; the presentation window, and the focus window. The focus window (passed in to [IDirect3D9::CreateDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) is used for handling events such as switching from foreground to background, or Alt+Tab. The presentation window is passed in to the D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS structure and is used solely as a canvas for Direct3D.

You should mark one of the windows you create (probably the first one) as the focus window. Share the focus window across devices but keep the "canvas" (presentation) windows separate.

**EDIT:** [This](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/356027-directx-9-multimonitor-devices/page__view__findpost__p__4908277) may help you as well.

> create a focus window for both devices.
>
> (optionally) create a device window for the first adapter.
>
> create a device window for the second adapter.
>
> create a direct3d9 context.
>
> use this to create both devices.
>
> create the first fullscreen device using the shared focus window and (optionally) the first device window.
>
> create the second fullscreen device using the shared focus window and the second device window.
>
> reset the first device.
>
> the shared focus window is passed directly as a parameter to CreateDevice.
>
> the device windows are passed in the presentation parameters structure.

Answer (score 3):

**Q>** Currently I'm getting an 'invalid params' HRESULT when calling          CreateDevice the second time. It works fine if one of the windows is 
full-screen, but not both.

**Because you were creating two different devices using a same adapter id 0. Use the adater id as 1 for the second create device call !**

Important step to be done after the creation of device 2 or 3 or 4... is to **reset the device one (default device id 0).**

```
Create Device 1
Create Device 2
........
........
Create Device n    
Reset Device 1
```

For to make your and another's life easier I have added a **working code** for supporting Multiple Monitors in Full Screen (Directx 9). Please note that I have added/changed few lines of code from the sample code took from the web link you have mentioned in your question.

```
#define STRICT
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>
#include "resource.h"

// define the screen resolution
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 1920
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 1080

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// GLOBALS
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
LPDIRECT3D9 g_pD3D = NULL;
HWND g_hWnd_0 = NULL; // Handle to the first window
HWND g_hWnd_1 = NULL; // Handle to the second window

LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 g_pd3dDevice_0 = NULL; // Direct3d device for the first window
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 g_pd3dDevice_1 = NULL; // Direct3d device for the second window

LPD3DXMESH g_pTeapotMesh_0 = NULL; // The two devices can't share resources, so we'll
LPD3DXMESH g_pTeapotMesh_1 = NULL; // have to create two meshes... one for each device

D3DMATERIAL9 g_teapotMtrl;
D3DLIGHT9 g_pLight0;

LPD3DXFONT g_pd3dxFont = NULL;

DWORD g_dwBackBufferWidth = 0;
DWORD g_dwBackBufferHeight = 0;

bool windowed = false;

float g_fSpinX = 0.0f;
float g_fSpinY = 0.0f;

double g_dElpasedFrameTime = 0.0f;
double g_dElpasedAppTime = 0.0f;
double g_dCurrentTime = 0.0f;
double g_dLastTime = 0.0f;

struct Vertex
{
    float x, y, z; // Position of vertex in 3D space
    float nx, ny, nz; // Normal for lighting calculations
    DWORD diffuse; // Diffuse color of vertex

    enum FVF
    {
        FVF_Flags = D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_NORMAL | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE
    };
};

#define TWO

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// PROTOTYPES
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
void CreateFont(void);
void init_0(void);
void init_1(void);
void shutDown_0(void);
void shutDown_1(void);
void render_0(void);
void render_1(void);
void LoadModels(void);
void ResetDevice(void);

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: WinMain()
// Desc: The application's entry point
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow )
{
    WNDCLASSEX winClass;
    MSG uMsg;
    bool deviceReset = FALSE;

    memset(&uMsg,0,sizeof(uMsg));
    winClass.lpszClassName = "MY_WINDOWS_CLASS";
    winClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    winClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    winClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    winClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    winClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, (LPCTSTR)IDI_DIRECTX_ICON);
    winClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hInstance, (LPCTSTR)IDI_DIRECTX_ICON);
    winClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    winClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    winClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    winClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    winClass.cbWndExtra = 0;

    if(!RegisterClassEx( &winClass) )
        return E_FAIL;

    //
    // Create window #0...
    //

    g_hWnd_0 = CreateWindowEx( NULL, "MY_WINDOWS_CLASS",
        "Direct3D (DX9) - Multiple Devices (Window #0)",
        WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_POPUP, // fullscreen values /* WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,*/
        0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL );

    if( g_hWnd_0 == NULL )
        return E_FAIL;

    ShowWindow( g_hWnd_0, nCmdShow );
    UpdateWindow( g_hWnd_0 );

#ifdef TWO
    //
    // Create window #1...
    //
    g_hWnd_1 = CreateWindowEx( NULL, "MY_WINDOWS_CLASS",
        "Direct3D (DX9) - Multiple Devices (Window #1)",
        WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_POPUP, // fullscreen values /* WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,*/
        1920, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL );

    if( g_hWnd_1 == NULL )
        return E_FAIL;

    ShowWindow( g_hWnd_1, nCmdShow );
    UpdateWindow( g_hWnd_1 );
#endif
    //
    // Init Direct3D usage on both windows...
    //

    init_0();
#ifdef TWO
    init_1();
#endif

    ResetDevice(); // Important !!!

    LoadModels();

    while( uMsg.message != WM_QUIT )
    {
        if( PeekMessage( &uMsg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) )
        {
            TranslateMessage( &uMsg );
            DispatchMessage( &uMsg );
        }
        else
        {
            g_dCurrentTime = timeGetTime();
            g_dElpasedFrameTime = g_dCurrentTime - g_dLastTime; // How much time has passed since the last frame?
            g_dElpasedAppTime += g_dElpasedFrameTime; // How much time has passed overall for the application?
            g_dLastTime = g_dCurrentTime;

            render_0();
#ifdef TWO
            render_1();
#endif
        }
    }

    //
    // Cleanup Direct3D usage on both windows...
    //
#ifdef TWO
    shutDown_1();
#endif
    shutDown_0();

    UnregisterClass( "MY_WINDOWS_CLASS", winClass.hInstance );
    return uMsg.wParam;
}

void ResetDevice(void)
{
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
    d3dpp.Windowed = windowed;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = g_hWnd_0;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_FLIP;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = SCREEN_WIDTH; // set the width of the buffer
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT; // set the height of the buffer
    d3dpp.BackBufferCount = 1;
    d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
    d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;
    d3dpp.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_ONE;
    g_pd3dDevice_0->Reset(&d3dpp);
}

void LoadModels(void)
{
    D3DXMATRIX matProj;
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH( &matProj, D3DXToRadian(45.0f), 1920.0f / 1080.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f );
    g_pd3dDevice_0->SetTransform( D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProj );

    g_pd3dDevice_0->SetRenderState( D3DRS_ZENABLE, TRUE );
    g_pd3dDevice_0->SetRenderState( D3DRS_LIGHTING, TRUE );
    g_pd3dDevice_0->SetRenderState( D3DRS_SPECULARENABLE, TRUE );

    // Setup a material for the teapot
    ZeroMemory( &g_teapotMtrl, sizeof(D3DMATERIAL9) );

    g_teapotMtrl.Diffuse.r = 1.0f;
    g_teapotMtrl.Diffuse.g = 1.0f;
    g_teapotMtrl.Diffuse.b = 1.0f;
    g_teapotMtrl.Diffuse.a = 1.0f;

    // Setup a simple directional light and some ambient...
    g_pLight0.Type = D3DLIGHT_DIRECTIONAL;
    g_pLight0.Direction = D3DXVECTOR3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );

    g_pLight0.Diffuse.r = 1.0f;
    g_pLight0.Diffuse.g = 1.0f;
    g_pLight0.Diffuse.b = 1.0f;
    g_pLight0.Diffuse.a = 1.0f;

    g_pLight0.Specular.r = 1.0f;
    g_pLight0.Specular.g = 1.0f;
    g_pLight0.Specular.b = 1.0f;
    g_pLight0.Specular.a = 1.0f;

    g_pd3dDevice_0->SetLight( 0, &g_pLight0 );
    g_pd3dDevice_0->LightEnable( 0, TRUE );

    g_pd3dDevice_0->SetRenderState( D3DRS_AMBIENT, D3DCOLOR_COLORVALUE( 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f ) );

    // Load up the teapot mesh...
    D3DXLoadMeshFromX( "teapot.x", D3DXMESH_SYSTEMMEM, g_pd3dDevice_0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &g_pTeapotMesh_0 );

    CreateFont();

#ifndef TWO
    return;
#endif

    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH( &matProj, D3DXToRadian(45.0f), 1920.0f / 1080.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f );
    g_pd3dDevice_1->SetTransform( D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProj );

    g_pd3dDevice_1->SetRenderState( D3DRS_ZENABLE, TRUE );
    g_pd3dDevice_1->SetRenderState( D3DRS_LIGHTING, TRUE );
    g_pd3dDevice_1->SetRenderState( D3DRS_SPECULARENABLE, TRUE );

    // Setup a material for the teapot
    ZeroMemory( &g_teapotMtrl, sizeof(D3DMATERIAL9) );

    g_teapotMtrl.Diffuse.r = 1.0f;
    g_teapotMtrl.Diffuse.g = 1.0f;
    g_teapotMtrl.Diffuse.b = 1.0f;
    g_teapotMtrl.Diffuse.a = 1.0f;

    // Setup a simple directional light and some ambient...
    g_pLight0.Type = D3DLIGHT_DIRECTIONAL;
    g_pLight0.Direction = D3DXVECTOR3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );

    g_pLight0.Diffuse.r = 1.0f;
    g_pLight0.Diffuse.g = 1.0f;
    g_pLight0.Diffuse.b = 1.0f;
    g_pLight0.Diffuse.a = 1.0f;

    g_pLight0.Specular.r = 1.0f;
    g_pLight0.Specular.g = 1.0f;
    g_pLight0.Specular.b = 1.0f;
    g_pLight0.Specular.a = 1.0f;

    g_pd3dDevice_1->SetLight( 0, &g_pLight0 );
    g_pd3dDevice_1->LightEnable( 0, TRUE );

    g_pd3dDevice_1->SetRenderState( D3DRS_AMBIENT, D3DCOLOR_COLORVALUE( 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f ) );

    // Load up the teapot mesh...
    D3DXLoadMeshFromX( "teapot.x", D3DXMESH_SYSTEMMEM, g_pd3dDevice_1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &g_pTeapotMesh_1 );
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: WindowProc()
// Desc: The window's message handler
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    static POINT ptLastMousePosit;
    static POINT ptCurrentMousePosit;
    static bool bMousing;

    switch( msg )
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            switch( wParam )
            {
            case VK_ESCAPE:
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                break;
            }
        }
        break;

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        {
            ptLastMousePosit.x = ptCurrentMousePosit.x = LOWORD (lParam);
            ptLastMousePosit.y = ptCurrentMousePosit.y = HIWORD (lParam);
            bMousing = true;
        }
        break;

    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        {
            bMousing = false;
        }
        break;

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        {
            ptCurrentMousePosit.x = LOWORD (lParam);
            ptCurrentMousePosit.y = HIWORD (lParam);

            if( bMousing )
            {
                g_fSpinX -= (ptCurrentMousePosit.x - ptLastMousePosit.x);
                g_fSpinY -= (ptCurrentMousePosit.y - ptLastMousePosit.y);
            }

            ptLastMousePosit.x = ptCurrentMousePosit.x;
            ptLastMousePosit.y = ptCurrentMousePosit.y;
        }
        break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        }

    case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        }
        break;

    default:
        {
            return DefWindowProc( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
        }
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}

void CreateFont( void )
{
    HRESULT hr;
    HDC hDC;
    //HFONT hFont;
    int nHeight;
    int nPointSize = 9;
    //char strFontName[] = "Arial";

    hDC = GetDC( NULL );

    nHeight = -( MulDiv( nPointSize, GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSY), 72 ) );

    ReleaseDC( NULL, hDC );

    // Create a font for statistics and help output
    hr = D3DXCreateFont( g_pd3dDevice_0, nHeight, 0, FW_BOLD, 0, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, TEXT("Arial"), &g_pd3dxFont );

    if( FAILED( hr ) ) MessageBox(NULL, "Call to D3DXCreateFont failed!", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: init_0()
// Desc:
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void init_0( void )
{
    g_pD3D = Direct3DCreate9( D3D_SDK_VERSION );

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
    ZeroMemory( &d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp) );

    d3dpp.Windowed = windowed;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = g_hWnd_0;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_FLIP;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = SCREEN_WIDTH; // set the width of the buffer
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT; // set the height of the buffer
    d3dpp.BackBufferCount = 1;
    d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
    d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;
    d3dpp.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_ONE;

    g_pD3D->CreateDevice( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, g_hWnd_0, D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &g_pd3dDevice_0 );

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: init_1()
// Desc:
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void init_1( void )
{
    HWND window;

    if(!windowed)
    {
        window = g_hWnd_0;
    }
    else
    {
        window = g_hWnd_1;
    }

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
    ZeroMemory( &d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp) );
    d3dpp.Windowed = windowed;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = window;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_FLIP;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = SCREEN_WIDTH; // set the width of the buffer
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT; // set the height of the buffer
    d3dpp.BackBufferCount = 1;
    d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
    d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;
    d3dpp.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_ONE;

    g_pD3D->CreateDevice( 1, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, window, D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &g_pd3dDevice_1 );

}


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: shutDown()
// Desc:
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void shutDown_0( void )
{
    if( g_pTeapotMesh_0 != NULL )
        g_pTeapotMesh_0->Release();

    if( g_pd3dDevice_0 != NULL )
        g_pd3dDevice_0->Release();

    if( g_pD3D != NULL )
        g_pD3D->Release();
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: shutDown()
// Desc:
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void shutDown_1( void )
{
    if( g_pTeapotMesh_1 != NULL )
        g_pTeapotMesh_1->Release();

    if( g_pd3dDevice_1 != NULL )
        g_pd3dDevice_1->Release();
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: render_0()
// Desc:
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void render_0( void )
{
    D3DXMATRIX matView;
    D3DXMATRIX matWorld;
    D3DXMATRIX matRotation;
    D3DXMATRIX matTranslation;
    static int nFrameCount = 0;
    static double nTimeOfLastFPSUpdate = 0.0;
    static char fpsString[50] = "Frames Per Second = ";
    RECT destRect;

    // Now we can clear just view-port's portion of the buffer to red...
    g_pd3dDevice_0->Clear( 0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, D3DCOLOR_COLORVALUE( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ), 1.0f, 0 );

    g_pd3dDevice_0->BeginScene();

    // For the left view-port, leave the view at the origin...
    D3DXMatrixIdentity( &matView );
    g_pd3dDevice_0->SetTransform( D3DTS_VIEW, &matView );

    // ... and use the world matrix to spin and translate the teapot
    // out where we can see it...
    D3DXMatrixRotationYawPitchRoll( &matRotation, D3DXToRadian(g_fSpinX), D3DXToRadian(g_fSpinY), 0.0f );
    D3DXMatrixTranslation( &matTranslation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f );
    matWorld = matRotation * matTranslation;
    g_pd3dDevice_0->SetTransform( D3DTS_WORLD, &matWorld );

    g_pd3dDevice_0->SetMaterial( &g_teapotMtrl );
    g_pTeapotMesh_0->DrawSubset(0);

    g_pd3dDevice_0->EndScene();

    // Report frames per second and the number of objects culled...
    ++nFrameCount;

    if( g_dElpasedAppTime - nTimeOfLastFPSUpdate > 1000 ) // Update once a second
    {
        sprintf( fpsString, "Frames Per Second = %4.2f", nFrameCount*1000.0/(g_dElpasedAppTime - nTimeOfLastFPSUpdate) );

        nTimeOfLastFPSUpdate = g_dElpasedAppTime;
        nFrameCount = 0;
    }

    SetRect( &destRect, 5, 5, 0, 0 );

    g_pd3dxFont->DrawText( NULL, fpsString, -1, &destRect, DT_NOCLIP, D3DXCOLOR( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) );

    g_pd3dDevice_0->Present( NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: render_1()
// Desc:
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void render_1( void )
{
    D3DXMATRIX matView;
    D3DXMATRIX matWorld;
    D3DXMATRIX matRotation;
    D3DXMATRIX matTranslation;

    // Now we can clear just view-port's portion of the buffer to green...
    g_pd3dDevice_1->Clear( 0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, D3DCOLOR_COLORVALUE( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ), 1.0f, 0 );

    g_pd3dDevice_1->BeginScene();

    // For the left view-port, leave the view at the origin...
    D3DXMatrixIdentity( &matView );
    g_pd3dDevice_1->SetTransform( D3DTS_VIEW, &matView );

    // ... and use the world matrix to spin and translate the teapot
    // out where we can see it...
    D3DXMatrixRotationYawPitchRoll( &matRotation, D3DXToRadian(g_fSpinX), D3DXToRadian(g_fSpinY), 0.0f );
    D3DXMatrixTranslation( &matTranslation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f );
    matWorld = matRotation * matTranslation;
    g_pd3dDevice_1->SetTransform( D3DTS_WORLD, &matWorld );


    g_pd3dDevice_1->SetMaterial( &g_teapotMtrl );
    g_pTeapotMesh_1->DrawSubset(0);

    g_pd3dDevice_1->EndScene();

    // We're done! Now, we just call Present()
    g_pd3dDevice_1->Present( NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code example (helped me a lot)! However, `init_1()` has the defect that it uses the same argument `window` for `d3dpp.hDeviceWindow` and as argument for `CreateDevice`. This fails for the case `windowed=false` (as outlined in the other answer). The correct way would be to use `hDeviceWindow=g_hWnd_1`.